# Unable to assign an Id to the dynamically generated Ckeditor

Tags: jquery, iframe, ckeditor

I have many ckeditor instances getting generated dynamically in one page and in the ckeditor's instanceReady function I get hold of each ckeditor's instance and from there on I get the iFrame's reference to which I assign an id. Now, after assigning an id when I say iFrameDocument.getElementById(assignedIframeId) Iam unable to find the iFrame. Here's my code :

```
<html>
<body>
    <!-- This is the template. The div tag with class="contents" will be replaced with CKEditor -->
    <script type="text/html" id="PS_ItemViewModel-template">
        <div id="mgrComments" class="document comment-region">
            <div class="contents" data-bind="html : mgrComments"></div>
        </div>
    </script>
            <!-- looping the template based on the number of items -->
            <div class="ps-item-container" data-bind="foreach : psItems">
       <div data-bind="template : {'name' : 'PS_ItemViewModel-template'}, event 
:   {psItemSetupEditor : _setupEditor, psItemRefreshEditor : _refreshEditor}"></div>                                                    
             </div>
</body>
</html>

// In the javascript file ...
    self._setupEditor = function(data, event){
    var domNode = event.currentTarget;
    self.editor = self._injectEditorInstance($(domNode).find('div#mgrComments   div.contents'), self.mgrComments, self.headerNode, self.criterionNodes);
}

self._injectEditorInstance = function(commentNode, initialText, headerNode, criterionNodes) {
    $('div#editor-toolbar').show();

    commentNode.ckeditor(function(){
        console.log("Inside commentNode.ckeditor ...");
        var editor = this;

        this.setData(initialText, function(){
            //Handles direct changes to editor contents
            editor.on('setData', function() {
                self.editorChangeHandler(editor);
            });

            //Handles paste
            editor.on('paste', function() {
                console.log("In paste event ...");
                self.editorChangeHandler(editor);
            });
        });
    }, {customConfig : '/simple_eval/js/ckeditor/SimpleEvalEditorConfig.js'});

    return commentNode.ckeditorGet();   
};

$(document).ready(function() {  


CKEDITOR.on("instanceReady", function(e) {
    console.log("In instanceReady ...................................");
    var assignedId  =   e.editor.name + "jspell";
    $("#cke_contents_" + e.editor.name+" iframe").attr("id", assignedId);
    var iframeDoc   =   null;
    $('#'+assignedId).each( 
                function(){ iframeDoc=this.contentWindow.document;}
                );
            console.log(" innerDoc Element = "+iframeDoc.getElementById(assignedId));
    fieldsToCheck[fieldsToCheck.length] = [iframeDoc, assignedId];
    jspellInit();
   });


});

var fieldsToCheck = new Array();
function getSpellCheckArray() { 
console.log("In getSpellCheckArray ...................................");
   return fieldsToCheck;
}
```

In the code above, when I say console.log(" innerDoc Element = "+iframeDoc.getElementById(assignedId)); it prints out null, which means the element was not found in the iframe document.
Can somebody suggest me on how to assign an id to a ckeditor's iframe such that it can retrieved by using the iframe's assigned id.

Thanks.

Comment: maybe this will help `$('iframe').contents().find('#target_id');` obviously it may not work as it is but the key is you need to use `.contents()` or `.content()` to go inside the iframe :)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. At least this did not give me null but neither did it solve my purpose. Actually, I am trying to integrate jSpell with ckeditor and the way jSpell works is that jSpell looks for a document object and the element on which spell check can be done.Therefore I was trying to get hold of the document object of the iFrame so that when i say document.getElementById("editor1jspell") then it should be able to find the editor so that the editor contents will be available for spell check. Any suggestion on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can assign an ID to the HTML `<body>` of each instance and use that to get the content block.

Because you are creating multiple instances, I'll assume that you are using `CKEDITOR.replaceAll()`.

You can assign an ID to each content body when the instances are created. I'm creating the `<body>` ID by adding "body" to the `<textarea>` ID.

```
CKEDITOR.replaceAll( function(textarea, config) {    
  // Assume all textareas to be edited will have class "ckeditor"
  if (!(textarea.className=="testing")) {
    return false;
  }

  config.bodyId = textarea.id + 'body';
});
```

---

Then in the "instanceReady" function, grab the instance name (which is the same as the textarea ID) and add "body" to it, this will give you the ID of the content area that contains the text to be spell checked.

You can get the iFrame doc with `e.editor.document`.

```
var fieldsToCheck;

CKEDITOR.on("instanceReady", function(e) {
  console.log(e.editor.name);
  console.log(e.editor.document);

  var assignedId = e.editor.name + "body";
  fieldsToCheck[fieldsToCheck.length] = [e.editor.document, assignedId];
});
```

---

If you are need to set the `fieldsToCheck` array when the spell check is triggered, you can loop through the instances array.

```
$("#test_button").click(function(){
  var fieldsToCheck;

  $.each(CKEDITOR.instances, function () {
    console.log(this.name);
    console.log(this.document);

    var assignedId = this.name + "body";
    fieldsToCheck[fieldsToCheck.length] = [this.document, assignedId];
  });
});
```

---

**Updated July 26th**

I took your document ready section and made some changes. I commented out the items I replaced and put the new version beneath the commented out portion. The iframe is being assigned the ID. I don't know what names are being assigned to the instances, but as long as they're unique, the ID's will be unique.

It may not be apparent, but the CkEditor `on.instanceReady` method is called separately for each instance created, so you may want to move the`jspellInit()` function call outside of the `instanceReady` function and let it work with the `fieldsToCheck` array after all of the instances have been added to the array .

I also added some `console.log()` statements that contain the actual CkEditor object. You can see the properties and methods available in case you need to change something.

Be sure to read the **note** at the end.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    var fieldsToCheck=new Array();
    var editorCount = 0;

    CKEDITOR.on("instanceReady", function(e) {
        console.log("In instanceReady ...................................");
        console.log(e);
        console.log(e.editor);

        var assignedId  =   e.editor.name + "jspell";

    //    $("#cke_contents_" + e.editor.name+" iframe").attr("id", assignedId);
        $("#cke_contents_" + e.editor.name+" iframe").context.activeElement.id = assignedId;

    //    var iframeDoc   =   null;    
        var iframeDoc = $('#'+assignedId)[0].contentDocument;

    //    $('#'+assignedId).each( 
    //        function(){ iframeDoc=this.contentWindow.document;}
    //    );


    //    This won't work, iframeDoc is inside the iFrame with id=assignedId
    //    console.log(" innerDoc Element = "+iframeDoc.getElementById(assignedId));
        console.log(iframeDoc);

        var editorBody = e.editor.document.getBody();
        editorBody.setAttribute("id", "TESTsetBODYid"+editorCount);
        console.log(editorBody);
        editorCount += 1;

        fieldsToCheck[fieldsToCheck.length] = [iframeDoc, assignedId];
        console.log(fieldsToCheck);
        jspellInit();
    });
});
```

---

**Note**

I haven't worked with jSpell, so I'm not sure what you really need to put into the `fieldsToCheck` array, but right now `iframeDoc` contains the full HTML code (`<head> and <body>`) found within the iframe. The `assignedId` variable contains the ID of the iframe.

It seems to me that to do spell checking, you want the contents of the `<body>` element, so I included an example of the `getBody()` method just before the `fieldsToCheck` array is created. I also included an example of how to set the ID of the body.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But in my application the ckeditors are generated dynamically. Its not replacing any textareas.In that case how do I assign an id to the dynamically generated ckeditors and how do I retrieve the editor with that assigned id.

Comment: What do you mean by the editors are generated dynamically? Are you assigning the class "ckeditor" to each textarea? Please add the code that generates them dynamically to your answer or I can't answer your question.

Comment: Hey Codewaggle, I have added the code where the the div tags are replaced by CKEditors

Comment: Let me know if you have any questions.